# What things would I have to learn to understand the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer Conjecture?

Tags: self-learning, conjectures

Hopefully I'm accepted into grad. school this year—but, in the meantime, I've been lost as to what to study, outside of just going through textbooks.

I've decided to study a *particular* problem (I've found it difficult to find problems outside of being in school), and for this I'm trying to learn everything I can in order to understand the problem well. Hopefully, this will give me a bit more context, even if it necessitates going through textbooks (which I don't mind! I'm just struggling with direction.)

From reading it (the conjecture) I definitely want to further my studies in algebra?

Comment: Start with Silverman's "Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves."

Comment: As anomaly said, and a proof of the prime number theorem, and the theory of elliptic curves with complex multiplication, their L-function, Galois representation and modular form.

Comment: Thank you both. If you care enough, I'll accept an answer if you provide your comment in answer form.